# How do we perform POST operation using publish and subscribe in JMS for asynchronous calls?

Tags: java, jms

Consider the endpoint as "abc" and method as "POST".
I need JSON request and response using Publish/Subscribe in JMS for asynchronous call.

Comment: POST is an HTTP operation, in JMS messages are published in queues or topics. Can you please clarify what you are trying to do, the server you are using, etc.

Comment: Exactly, I want to write an API using pub/sub to perform POST operation.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. You need to narrow down your question to something specific that you're having a problem with. Right now your question is way too vague.